# Installing Windows 10 alongside Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

Is it possible to use free offer and install Windows 10 Home alongside Windows 7 Home Premium on another partition in dual boot mode ? I would like to try new version of OS but I am not sure if this is right choice for me. Even if my laptop has decent computing power (Intel Core i3-370M Nehalem architecture, 8GB RAM, 480 GB Intel SSD disk, 1 TB HDD drive) it is 5 year old. I am using it actively for developing with swap file disabled already 5 years ago after I bought it. After I upgrade to Windows 10 I am not sure if 8 GB will be enough for all the programs I am using (Visual Studio 2015, browsers). I would therefore prefer to install Windows 10 parallel with my existing Windows 7 installation which have myriad of programs installed into it. I would not be glad to find out that some of my favorite software ceased to function after upgrade. Is it technically possible to install free Windows 10 Home alongside existing Windows 7 Home Premium installation ? Is it permitted by license ?

Comment: Have you considered using say VMPlayer and installing a trial version of Windows 10 there? My home PC only has 4GB of ram and I can run VS 2015 without much problem, start up takes a bit, but after that not much difference in performance after the upgrade.

Comment: I want to have Windows 10 installed permanently with Windows 7 if possible and using one of them as my primary system (which one I determine after some time actively using Windows 10). Its good for testing my programs on various platforms.

Comment: I'm not to up on licensing, but something tells me this would require a seperate license since typically an upgrade license implys an upgrade. 

I figured if just testing if applications would work, a VM would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It doesn't work that way. It is a free ***upgrade*** which uses the existing license. To run both Windows 7 and Windows 10 via dual boot, you will need to purchase a Windows 10 license. ([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/free-upgrade-from-windows-7-to-windows-10-dual/29b232b2-ac67-45d6-be88-ac14b0c7bf8e?auth=1))

Of course, if you want to see if Windows 10 will run on your PC, you can download and install Windows 10 Enterprise for a [free 90-day evaluation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise) before making the decision to buy.